# get Membership user object from another model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-membership

i want something like this :

```
public class Order
{
    public Guid OrderID { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> orderDetailByOrderID { get; set; }
    public virtual MembershipUser userByOrderID { get; }
}
```

so from above code i want membership user to be access from Order object ....
however i tried it but its not working.

so please suggest some solution if you have come across this type situation

Comment: what do you mean it is not working? Why did you make `userByOrderID` read-only? You need to assign a value to it somewhere. At least make it `private set`.

Comment: its not working with set so better i tried it with readonly ....

Comment: Show us the code that you use to populate an object of type Order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might be using Entity Framework Code First. If this is the case you'd probably want:

`public virtual aspnet_Membership userByOrderID { get; set; }`

instead of

`public virtual MembershipUser userByOrderID { get; }`

That would grab the `aspnet_Membership` entity that is tied to the `UserId` foreign key. The `aspnet_Membership` class is not quite the same as the `MembershipUser` entity, but they have many of the same properties.

If that won't work, you can always use your `Order` model as is, and generate a ViewModel that has the `MembershipUser` object.

```
public class OrderViewModel
{
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public MembershipUser User { get; set; }
}
```

and create the ViewModel like this before passing it into a view

```
Order order = EntityDataContext.Orders.First();
var model = new OrderViewModel { Order = order, User = Membership.GetUser(order.UserId) }
```